# References about the exponent of automorphism groups of finite groups.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

I will be pleased if one can help me to find any reference talking about the exponent of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, $G$ denotes a finite group.  I'm specially interested to the case when $G$ is a finite $p$-group, and to the exponent of the group of automorphisms centralizing the frattini quotient.

Comment: [This MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68109/orders-of-automorphism-groups-of-p-groups) points out that if $|G|=p^n$ then $|\operatorname{Aut}(G)|$ divides $\Pi_{k=0}^{n-1} (p^{n}-p^{k})$ (and there is a $G$ such that $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ has order $\Pi_{k=0}^{n-1} (p^{n}-p^{k})$). Therefore, $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ has exponent dividing $\Pi_{k=0}^{n-1} (p^{n}-p^{k})$.

Comment: For general $G$ one result which might be useful is the fact that any automorphism of $G$ has order at most $|G| - 1$. A proof can be found in "Finite Group Theory" by Isaacs.

Comment: @user1729, of course a bound on the order provides a bound on the exponent. I thinked about more refined results.

Comment: Is there other results, that give a bound on the exponent of $Aut(G)$ in terms of other invariants of $G$? ( for instance its exponent and its nilpotency class if it is nilpotent)

Comment: I was unsure what you knew - and this was the best I could do off the top of my head! Although, Jack Schmidt is pretty active here, and his is a fine answer in the linked question.

Comment: Well, the exponent of $G/Z(G)$ gives a lower bound!

Comment: @user1729, Of course I'm grateful for your answer, what I meant is that I know what you indicated.  Thank you.

Comment: What about an upper bound?

Comment: As m.k. said, $|G|-1$.

Answer (score 0):

See articles of Evgenii Khukhro:

http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?&personid=18789&option_lang=eng

Maybe you could find in them something interesting for you.

Comment: Thank you dear Boris novikov.